# How to get user information on who triggered our Cloud Scheduler Job - Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm working on a Google Cloud project that has access to many users, I just found out that someone triggered a Cloud Scheduler job and was curious to know if there is a way I can find the person who did that.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add explanation to the link provided at the comment section, here's how to check your audit logs through [Activity Page](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/activity?_ga=2.21229042.832923137.1618793773-1720024288.1618793217):

1. Go to Navigation Menu > Home > Activity
2. See the email address of the person who triggered your Cloud Scheduler job by finding this resource name: `google.cloud.scheduler.v1.CloudScheduler.RunJob`
3. (Optional) You can filter the resource type to narrow down the search. Click **Resource Type** on the right part of the screen and only check **Audited Resource**.